# Trouble settings visibility for a block

Tags: blocks

So I have a block (just a image hyperlink) that is giving me a headache, due to it not showing up where I want it to do. Inside the block it self I've set the visibility settings to "Only show on sites in the list" and added the specific site in that list. 
I've tried different permutations of the site url and tried adding a / and a /* to no avail.

If I set the visibility setting to "Show on all sites" then it shows up on all sites at exactly the place I want it to be, except only on one page.

If anyone can help me with this I'd really appreciate it, never used Drupal before and I can't seem to find any information to help me debug this.

I'm using Drupal 6.26 if that makes a difference.

Comment: what pages do you want the block to show?

Comment: The block is an image, which when the user clicks it loads up a new site. This block is to be shown on a sub site under the domain, and I've added this page url to the list of pages that the block should be shown own (the settings of which are under blocks->'this specific block'). When I choose, in the same settings, that the block should be shown on all sites under the domain it does. It just doesn't follow the set rule, and that is my problem.